# connect kerio and openldap

Tags: linux, openldap

I am investigating kerio-connect email server. I am battling to get kerio and openldap to work together. LDAP users and groups are not appearing in kerio.

I have extended the OpenLDAP database with the Kerio objectclasses and attributes (see this [link](http://kb.kerio.com/product/kerio-connect/server-configuration/ldap-and-directory-services/mapping-users-groups-from-openldap-or-generic-ldap-server-294.html)). When I browse the LDAP directory these objectclasses and attributes are visible and usable.

The kerio and ldap servers are on different machines. The kerio server can connect to the LDAP server (there is a test button on the kerio admin website). From the machine running kerio server I can run ldap search queries.

**Question** 
Is the kerio openldap.map valid given the test LDAP user and group?
(I've also asked on the kerio forum: [question kerio forum](http://forums.kerio.com/m/113700/#msg_113700))

LDAP Server details:

- OS: Linux 3.11.0-15-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 9 18:16:27 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
- OpenLDAP: 2.4.31 slapd  (Ubuntu) (Oct  8 2013 20:51:43) 
  buildd@akateko:/build/buildd/openldap-2.4.31/debian/build/servers/slapd

Email Server details:

- OS: Debian GNU/Linux 7.4, x86_64
- Kerio Connect 8.2.4 (2550)

openldap.map:

```
<mapfile>
<map table="User">
<filter>objectclass=kerio-Mail-User</filter>
<active-attribute>kerio-Mail-Active</active-attribute>
<variable>
<name>Name</name>
<value><attribute>uid</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Account_enabled</name>
<value><attribute>kerio-Mail-AccountEnabled</attribute></value >
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Auth_type</name>
<value>5</value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>PIN</name>
<value><attribute>kerio-User-AuthPIN</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Rights</name>
<value><attribute>kerio-Mail-AdminRights</attribute></value >
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Authorization</name>
<value><attribute>kerio-Mail-Authorization</attribute></value >
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Groups</name>
<value><attribute>groupMemberShip</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>MailAddress</name>
<value><attribute>kerio-Mail-Address</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>ForwardMode</name>
<value><attribute>kerio-Mail-ForwardMode</attribute></value >
</variable>
<variable>
<name>ForwardAddress</name>
<value><attribute>kerio-Mail-ForwardAddress</attribute></value >
</variable>
<variable>
<name>HomeServer</name>
<value><attribute>kerio-Mail-HomeServer</attribute></value >
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Qstorage</name>
<value><attribute>kerio-Mail-QuotaStorage</attribute></value >
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Qmessage</name>
<value><attribute>kerio-Mail-QuotaMessage</attribute></value >
</variable>
<variable>
<name>MaxOutgoingMessageSize</name>
<value><attribute>kerio-Mail-MaxOutgoingMessageSize</attribute ></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>ReplyToAddress</name>
<value><attribute>kerio-Mail-WebReplyToAddress</attribute ></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Fullname</name>
<value><attribute>cn</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Description</name>
<value><attribute>description</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Guid</name>
<value><attribute type="string">apple-generateduid</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>LdapDN</name>
<value><dn /></value>
</variable> 
</map>  
<map table="Group">
<filter>objectclass=kerio-Mail-Group</filter>
<active-attribute>kerio-Mail-Active</active-attribute>
<variable>
<name>Name</name>
<value><attribute>cn</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>MailAddress</name>
<value><attribute>kerio-Mail-Address</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Rights</name>
<value><attribute>kerio-Mail-AdminRights</attribute></value >
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Authorization</name>
<value><attribute>kerio-Mail-Authorization</attribute></value >
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Description</name>
<value><attribute>description</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Guid</name>
<value><attribute type="string">apple-generateduid</attribute></value>
</variable>
</map>
</mapfile>
```

The test LDAP user and group are

```
dn: cn=keriotestuser,dc=flavia,dc=local
objectClass: kerio-Mail-User
objectClass: top
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
cn: keriotestuser
gidNumber: 1000
homeDirectory: /home/keriotestuser
sn: User
uid: keriotestuser
uidNumber: 1001
apple-generateduid: 7c17e30b-9a5d-4f2e-a11b-c8995a2aa99b
groupMemberShip: Group1
kerio-Mail-Active: 1
loginShell: /bin/bash
userPassword:: e1NTSEF9RTRGZTNmaDNzQkIxNXRWMFEzV041RGRLdngyZjU4RDc=
```

This is the LDAP Group

```
version: 1 
dn: cn=Group1,dc=flavia,dc=local
objectClass: kerio-Mail-Group
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: top
cn: Group1
member: cn=keriotestuser,dc=flavia,dc=local
apple-generateduid: a6b5c5d5-7121-4092-9f77-87fefdfebaf4
kerio-Mail-Active: 1
```

Other files which might be useful

gal_openldap.map

```
<mapfile>
<map table="User">
<filter> &amp;(objectclass=kerio-Mail-User)(kerio-Mail-Active=*)( !(kerio-
Mail-Authorization=kms.global.address.list.disabled) ) </filter>
<variable>
<name>Name</name>
<value><attribute>uid</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Account_enabled</name>
<value><attribute>kerio-Mail-AccountEnabled</attribute></value >
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Fullname</name>
<value><attribute>cn</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Title</name>
<value><attribute>title</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>TitleBefore</name>
<value><attribute>personalTitle</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>TitleAfter</name>
<value><attribute>generationQualifier</attribute></value >
</variable>
<variable>
<name>GivenName</name>
<value><attribute>givenName</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>MiddleName</name>
<value><attribute></attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Surname</name>
<value><attribute>sn</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Company</name>
<value><attribute>o</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Department</name>
<value><attribute>ou</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>HomeAddress</name>
<value><attribute>homePostalAddress</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>BA_pobox</name>
<value><attribute>postOfficeBox</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>BA_room</name>
<value><attribute>roomNumber</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>BA_street</name>
<value><attribute>street</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>BA_city</name>
<value><attribute>l</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>BA_zip</name>
<value><attribute>postalCode</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>BA_state</name>
<value><attribute>st</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>BA_country</name>
<value><attribute>c</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>PN_business</name>
<value><attribute>telephoneNumber</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>PN_home</name>
<value><attribute>homePhone</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>PN_mobile</name>
<value><attribute>mobile</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>PN_isdn</name>
<value><attribute>internationalISDNNumber</attribute></value >
</variable>
<variable>
<name>PN_fax</name>
<value><attribute>facsimileTelephoneNumber</attribute></value >
</variable>
<variable>
<name>PN_pager</name>
<value><attribute>pager</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>PN_telex</name>
<value><attribute>telexNumber</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>PN_ip</name>
<value><attribute>ipPhone</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>PN_other</name>
<value><attribute>otherTelephone</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>PN_otherfax</name>
<value><attribute>otherFacsimileTelephoneNumber</attribute ></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Email</name>
<value><attribute>kerio-Mail-Address</attribute><attribute >mail</attribute></value>
</variable>    
<variable>
<name>Image</name>
<value><attribute>jpegPhoto</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>UrlWork</name>
<value><attribute>labeledURI</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>UrlOther</name>
<value><attribute>apple-webloguri</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>IM_msn</name>
<value><attribute>apple-imhandle ~ MSN:([^\s]+)</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>IM_icq</name>
<value><attribute>apple-imhandle ~ ICQ:([^\s]+)</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>IM_aim</name>
<value><attribute>apple-imhandle ~ AIM:([^\s]+)</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>IM_yahoo</name>
<value><attribute>apple-imhandle ~ Yahoo:([^\s]+)</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>IM_jabber</name>
<value><attribute>apple-imhandle ~ JABBER:([^\s]+)</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Description</name>
<value><attribute>description</attribute></value>
</variable>
</map>
<map table="Group">
<filter> &amp;(objectclass=kerio-Mail-Group)(kerio-Mail-Address=* )(!(kerio-
Mail-Authorization=kms.global.address.list.disable d)) </filter>
<active-attribute>kerio-Mail-Active</active-attribute>
<variable>
<name>GroupName</name>
<value><attribute>cn</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Account_enabled</name>
<value><attribute>1</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Email</name>
<value><attribute>kerio-Mail-Address</attribute></value>
</variable>
<variable>
<name>Description</name>
<value><attribute>description</attribute></value>
</variable>
</map>
</mapfile>
```

kerio-mailserver.ldif

```
# AUTO-GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT!! Use ldapmodify.
# CRC32 e8c9384b
dn: cn=kerio,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: kerio
olcAttributeTypes: {0}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.1 NAME 'kerio-Mail-Active' EQU
ALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {1}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.2 NAME 'kerio-Mail-AccountEnab
led' EQUALITY integerMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE
)
olcAttributeTypes: {2}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.0.2.1 NAME 'kerio-User-AuthPIN' EQ
UALITY caseExactMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {3}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.5 NAME 'kerio-Mail-AdminRights
' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE
)
olcAttributeTypes: {4}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.6 NAME 'kerio-Mail-Address' EQ
UALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )
olcAttributeTypes: {5}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.7 NAME 'kerio-Mail-ForwardMode
' EQUALITY integerMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {6}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.8 NAME 'kerio-Mail-ForwardAddr
ess' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )
olcAttributeTypes: {7}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.9 NAME 'kerio-Mail-QuotaStorag
e' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE
)
olcAttributeTypes: {8}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.10 NAME 'kerio-Mail-QuotaMessa
ge' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALU
E )
olcAttributeTypes: {9}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.24 NAME 'kerio-Mail-Authorizat
ion' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )
olcAttributeTypes: {10}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.25 NAME 'kerio-Mail-HomeServe
r' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE
)
olcAttributeTypes: {11}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.26 NAME 'kerio-Mail-MaxOutgoi
ngMessageSize' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {12}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.22 NAME 'kerio-Mail-WebReplyT
oAddress' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGL
E-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {13}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.27 NAME 'kerio-Mail-Preferred
-Address' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGL
E-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {14}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.28 NAME 'groupMemberShip' EQU
ALITY caseExactIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )
olcAttributeTypes: {15}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.29 NAME 'apple-generateduid'
DESC 'generated unique ID' EQUALITY caseExactMatch SUBSTR caseExactSubstrings
Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcObjectClasses: {0}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.2.2.2.1 NAME 'kerio-Mail-User' SUP to
p AUXILIARY MAY ( kerio-Mail-Active $ kerio-Mail-AccountEnabled $ kerio-User-
AuthPIN $ kerio-Mail-AdminRights $ kerio-Mail-Authorization $ kerio-Mail-Addr
ess $ kerio-Mail-ForwardMode $ kerio-Mail-ForwardAddress $ kerio-Mail-QuotaSt
orage $ kerio-Mail-QuotaMessage $ kerio-Mail-HomeServer $ kerio-Mail-MaxOutgo
ingMessageSize $ kerio-Mail-WebReplyToAddress $ groupMemberShip $ apple-generateduid $
kerio-Mail-Preferred-Address ) )
olcObjectClasses: {1}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.2.2.2.2 NAME 'kerio-Mail-Group' SUP t
op AUXILIARY MAY ( kerio-Mail-Active $ kerio-Mail-AdminRights $ kerio-Mail-Au
thorization $ apple-generateduid $ kerio-Mail-Address ) )
```

kerio-mailserver.schema

```
#
# kerio-User attributes and class
#
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.1
NAME 'kerio-Mail-Active'
EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
SINGLE-VALUE ) 
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.2
NAME 'kerio-Mail-AccountEnabled'
EQUALITY integerMatch
SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27
SINGLE-VALUE ) 
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.0.2.1
NAME 'kerio-User-AuthPIN'
EQUALITY caseExactMatch
SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
SINGLE-VALUE )
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.5
NAME 'kerio-Mail-AdminRights'
EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
SINGLE-VALUE ) 
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.6
NAME 'kerio-Mail-Address'
EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )  
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.7
NAME 'kerio-Mail-ForwardMode'
EQUALITY integerMatch
SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27
SINGLE-VALUE ) 
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.8
NAME 'kerio-Mail-ForwardAddress'
EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 ) 
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.9
NAME 'kerio-Mail-QuotaStorage'
EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
SINGLE-VALUE ) 
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.10
NAME 'kerio-Mail-QuotaMessage'
EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
SINGLE-VALUE )  
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.24
NAME 'kerio-Mail-Authorization'
EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )   
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.25
NAME 'kerio-Mail-HomeServer'
EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
SINGLE-VALUE )
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.26
NAME 'kerio-Mail-MaxOutgoingMessageSize'
EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
SINGLE-VALUE )
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.22
NAME 'kerio-Mail-WebReplyToAddress'
EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
SINGLE-VALUE )
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.27
NAME 'kerio-Mail-Preferred-Address'
EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
SINGLE-VALUE ) 
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.28 NAME 'groupMemberShip'
EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match
SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.29
NAME ( 'apple-generateduid' )
DESC 'generated unique ID'
EQUALITY caseExactMatch
SUBSTR caseExactSubstringsMatch
SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE ) 
objectclass ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.2.2.2.1
NAME 'kerio-Mail-User'
AUXILIARY
SUP top
MAY (
kerio-Mail-Active $
kerio-Mail-AccountEnabled $
kerio-User-AuthPIN $
kerio-Mail-AdminRights $
kerio-Mail-Authorization $
kerio-Mail-Address $
kerio-Mail-ForwardMode $
kerio-Mail-ForwardAddress $
kerio-Mail-QuotaStorage $
kerio-Mail-QuotaMessage $
kerio-Mail-HomeServer $
kerio-Mail-MaxOutgoingMessageSize $
kerio-Mail-WebReplyToAddress $
groupMemberShip $
apple-generateduid $
kerio-Mail-Preferred-Address ) )  
objectclass ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.2.2.2.2
NAME 'kerio-Mail-Group'
AUXILIARY
SUP top
MAY (
kerio-Mail-Active $
kerio-Mail-AdminRights $
kerio-Mail-Authorization $
apple-generateduid $
kerio-Mail-Address ) )
```

cn={4}kerio.ldif

```
# AUTO-GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT!! Use ldapmodify.
# CRC32 84e834c7
dn: cn={4}kerio
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: {4}kerio
olcAttributeTypes: {0}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.1 NAME 'kerio-Mail-Active' EQU
ALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {1}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.2 NAME 'kerio-Mail-AccountEnab
led' EQUALITY integerMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE
)
olcAttributeTypes: {2}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.0.2.1 NAME 'kerio-User-AuthPIN' EQ
UALITY caseExactMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {3}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.5 NAME 'kerio-Mail-AdminRights
' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE
)
olcAttributeTypes: {4}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.6 NAME 'kerio-Mail-Address' EQ
UALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )
olcAttributeTypes: {5}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.7 NAME 'kerio-Mail-ForwardMode
' EQUALITY integerMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {6}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.8 NAME 'kerio-Mail-ForwardAddr
ess' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )
olcAttributeTypes: {7}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.9 NAME 'kerio-Mail-QuotaStorag
e' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE
)
olcAttributeTypes: {8}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.10 NAME 'kerio-Mail-QuotaMessa
ge' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALU
E )
olcAttributeTypes: {9}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.24 NAME 'kerio-Mail-Authorizat
ion' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )
olcAttributeTypes: {10}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.25 NAME 'kerio-Mail-HomeServe
r' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE
)
olcAttributeTypes: {11}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.26 NAME 'kerio-Mail-MaxOutgoi
ngMessageSize' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {12}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.22 NAME 'kerio-Mail-WebReplyT
oAddress' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGL
E-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {13}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.27 NAME 'kerio-Mail-Preferred
-Address' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGL
E-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {14}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.28 NAME 'groupMemberShip' EQU
ALITY caseExactIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )
olcAttributeTypes: {15}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.1.2.2.29 NAME 'apple-generateduid'
DESC 'generated unique ID' EQUALITY caseExactMatch SUBSTR caseExactSubstrings
Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcObjectClasses: {0}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.2.2.2.1 NAME 'kerio-Mail-User' SUP to
p AUXILIARY MAY ( kerio-Mail-Active $ kerio-Mail-AccountEnabled $ kerio-User-
AuthPIN $ kerio-Mail-AdminRights $ kerio-Mail-Authorization $ kerio-Mail-Addr
ess $ kerio-Mail-ForwardMode $ kerio-Mail-ForwardAddress $ kerio-Mail-QuotaSt
orage $ kerio-Mail-QuotaMessage $ kerio-Mail-HomeServer $ kerio-Mail-MaxOutgo
ingMessageSize $ kerio-Mail-WebReplyToAddress $ groupMemberShip $ apple-gener
ateduid $ kerio-Mail-Preferred-Address ) )
olcObjectClasses: {1}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10311.2.2.2.2 NAME 'kerio-Mail-Group' SUP t
op AUXILIARY MAY ( kerio-Mail-Active $ kerio-Mail-AdminRights $ kerio-Mail-Au
thorization $ apple-generateduid $ kerio-Mail-Address ) )
structuralObjectClass: olcSchemaConfig
entryUUID: 4d5c04ba-7616-1033-95f3-55880fae5256
creatorsName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
createTimestamp: 20140522160304Z
entryCSN: 20140522160304.647760Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
modifyTimestamp: 20140522160304Z
```

Comment: The kerio steps for openldap finally worked. I only had to read the document with a comb like a lawyer: [Mapping users/groups from OpenLDAP or Generic LDAP server ][1]

The files in the question should be correct.

Also the forum helps

 1. [OpenLdap Integration with Kerio Mail Server][2]



  [1]: http://kb.kerio.com/product/kerio-connect/server-configuration/ldap-and-directory-services/mapping-users-groups-from-openldap-or-generic-ldap-server-294.html
  [2]: http://forums.kerio.com/m/72180/

Answer (score 0):

The kerio steps for openldap finally worked. I only had to read the document with a comb like a lawyer: [Mapping users/groups from OpenLDAP or Generic LDAP server](http://kb.kerio.com/product/kerio-connect/server-configuration/ldap-and-directory-services/mapping-users-groups-from-openldap-or-generic-ldap-server-294.html)

The files in the question should be correct. Also the kerio forum helps: [OpenLdap Integration with Kerio Mail Server](http://forums.kerio.com/m/113533/#)